# PhoneGap push notification - bulding .apk getiing the error message

Tags: android, cordova, phonegap-build

Working on Phonegap push notification by following this

http://devgirl.org/2013/07/17/tutorial-implement-push-notifications-in-your-phonegap-application/

while building .apk using i'm getting this error..

:processDebugResources
E:\IonicProject\vinod\myApp\platforms\android\build\intermediates\manifests\full\debug\AndroidManife
st.xml:44:23-37 : AAPT: No resource found that matches the given name (at 'icon' with value '@drawab
le/icon').

FAILED

FAILURE:
Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:

Execution failed for task ':processDebugResources'.

>
com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: Process
'command 'E:\PrimaryInsatalations\adt-bundle-windows-x86_64-20140702\sdk\build-tools\22.0.1\aapt.exe
'' finished with non-zero exit value 1

- Try:

Run with
--stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug
 option to get more log output.

BUILD FAILED

Total time: 15.085 secs

Error: Error code 1 for command: cmd with args: /s,/c,"E:\IonicProject\vinod\myApp\platforms\android
\gradlew cdvBuildDebug -b E:\IonicProject\vinod\myApp\platforms\android\build.gradle -Dorg.gradle.da
emon=true -Pandroid.useDeprecatedNdk=true"

Comment: are you sure you are installing the Google Play services and Android support library and latest Android SDK Platform-tools from SDK Manager ?

Comment: Yes. I have installed.

Comment: do you get the same error when run it on actual (real) device ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It does not seem to be related to the push notification feature.

If you have custom code specific for android, look for `@drawable/icon`, it says the resource is missing, meaning you should have an actual file called `icon.png` (or another image extension) within `res/drawable` directory (or their density variants).

If you don't have custom native code, only JS, try removing the android platform and adding it back from your cordova/phonegap command line.

Comment: Couple of time i removed android platform and added using Cordova still getting the same error.

Comment: Did you try updating your toolset to the latest version, maybe it is a bug. Also double check your `config.xml` for any mistakes you might have there.

Comment: Create new application now it is working for me. But push notification is not working, while running node js application, it is displaying error message like invalid RegID but RegID and GCMnumber are correct. I verified it couple of times.

Comment: But then it seems an issue in the server side, not related to the topic here, right?

Comment: Exactly your correct @Filipe Esperandio, I'm look into the same.

Answer (score 1):

No resource found that matches the given name (at 'icon' with value '@drawab le/icon').

Your console is telling the error. There is no icon file in platforms/android/res/drawable.

So just put there an image file (png file of small dimension) named icon. And if possible put icon in all drawable folders according to their size.